# I am looking for a limited set of survey monkey features that is cheap

Tags: web-apps, javascript, survey, polls

First of all, my web app does not have a backend: it's front end only. **I want to be able to embed a survey in an HTML page, and I want to be able to pass variables into it.**

Here's what I'm going to use it for: I am making an html game, and when it ends, I want to give the player a survey about how they liked the content. I also have two other surveys in mind for different purposes.

Right now, I am using Google forms for my survey, but it does not allow you to pass in variables. Therefore, the only way I can figure out what version the player is playing (I don't expect anyone to take this in on my behalf), is to create a new Google form every time I create a version of the game. Now that I have three types of surveys I want to give per version, this is no longer scalable.

I looked into SurveyMonkey, and I can't figure out  if it can be passed variables. Regardless, the free plan only lets you look at 40 replies per survey. I was prepared to pony up some money, but then I saw that for $25 a month, you only get to see 10,000 responses per month, and I think that's no matter how many surveys I create. If the game is more popular,

Is there anything out there that is a good alternative? I only need the features I mentioned at the beginning.